# Sum a different range for each customer line on a table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a problem I am trying to solve and did not found similar issues in the website.

I have the following issue:

- each customer receives the software upgrade at a different month
- I want to see the number of logged-in customers before and after the software upgrade

(just new to this site cannot post an image)

So I have a sheet ("Software") database with customer per row (column A) and month per column (B5 to S5) with the number of log in each cell.

Then on another sheet I have the customer ID in column A and the month of software upgrade (column B).

On column C I want to create

```
=SUMIF(Software!$B$5:$S$5; ">" & B2; Software!XX:XX)
```

where `XX` searches the correct row on the database.

I then wanted to use this to get the `XX:XX` right:

```
=CELL("address";INDEX(Software!B:B;MATCH(A2;Software!A:A;0))) & ":" & CELL("address";INDEX(Software!S:S;MATCH(A2;Software!A:A;0)))
```

or a combination of "concatenate" and

```
=CELL("row";INDEX(Software!B:B;MATCH(A2;Software!A:A;0))) & ":" & CELL("row";INDEX(Software!S:S;MATCH(A2;Software!A:A;0)))
```

--> returning the right row

but I was not able to succeed.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX/MATCH` can refer to a whole row if you put a zero in the column ref, e.g. assuming up to 1000 rows of customer data try this formula

`=SUMIF(Software!$B$5:$S$5;">"&B2;INDEX(Software!$B$6:$S$1000;MATCH(A2;Software!$A$6:$A$1000;0);0))`